# how can resize dynamically the logo of the header?

Tags: html, css

Really I don't know nothing about html and css, but I have a webpage in which I can change the size of the page to adjust to the size of the resolution of the screen. I prefer that the page size would adjust to the size of the browser, but by the moment I can live with it.

In the page, I have a header that has am image as logo, but I can't get to resize to fit to the page size, and I would like to know if it is possible.

The code of my css file is:

```
/* Resets
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, body, html, p, blockquote, fieldset, input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a img {
    border: 0;
    /*NOTA: si se utiliza el width en la imagen se modifica el tamaño de la imagen del logo.
    Se puede utilizar tanto en porcentaje como en pxels, pero en porcentaje no parece que se modifique,
    solo si se indica en pixels.
    ESTO ES UN AÑADIDO propio, no es original de la web.*/
    width: 100%;
    /*@NOTA: eh height modica todas las imágenes del la página.*/
    //height: 100px;
}

a {
    color: #6ca9d5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #90cbf5;
}

/* General Styling and Structure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #868686;
    /*NOTA: el margen es el que se deja entre el borde del navegador y el contenido. Por defecto es 0.
    El padding es parecido y por defecto también es 0. Aunque se cambia y no hace nada.
    Se tiene que poner 10px por ejemplo, px para indicar pixels. Si se pone 10% entonces es en porcentaje.*/
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fafafa;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .3em 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: "Actor", "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#content h2 {
    color: #90cbf5;
}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 0;
}

#content p {
    color: #868686;
}

#content abbr {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #8f8f8f;
}


#header-wrap,
#main-wrap {
    background: #fff;
    /*@PRUEBA el original es el mind-width:1200px
    width: 100%;
    //min-width: 1200px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}


#page {
    /*@NOTA: esto no deja margen a los lados, si no se indica width, pega todo al máximo de la resolución de pantalla.
    Por defecto es 0 auto*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*@MODIFICACION: este es el valor original. Si se amplia a 1300px por ejemplo ocupa todo el ancho
    //de pantalla. Si no se pone nada, se pega todo a la pantalla sin márgenes.
    Se ajusta al tamaño de pantalla, no al tamaño de la ventana del navegador.*/
    /*width: 900px*/
    /*@NOTA: si se indica un ancho automático se ajusta también al tamaño de pantalla.
    Se ajusta al tamaño de pantalla, no al tamaño de la ventana del navegador.*/
    width: 100%;
}


#header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*@PRUEBA*/
    width: 2000px;
}

.wsite-logo,
.wsite-logo a {
    color: #90cbf5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wsite-logo,
.wsite-logo a:hover {
    color: #90cbf5;
}

#logo,
#logo a {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #90cbf5;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Actor", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header-right a {
    color: #6ca9d5;
}

#header-right a:hover {
    color: #90cbf5;
}

/* Header Area
-------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
    /*El ancho parece que no se ajusta a nada, si se pone muy pequeño el logo se sigue viendo
    completo*/
    width: 100%;
    /*@NOTA: esto modifica el alto del encabezado, que es dond está el logo.*/
    height: 100px;
}

#header,
#header table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#header td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*@NOTA: la alineación modifica la posición de la imagen de la cabecera de GTS.*/
    text-align: left;
}


#logo {
    /*@NOTA: el padding controla la separación desde la parte superior hasta la imagen del lgo de GTS.
    El primer número indica el padding desde la parte superior y el segundo desde la izquierda.
    El padding empieza a contar desde el margen de la página, es por tanto una adición al margen.
    Se pueden indicar también porcentajes.*/
    padding: 0 0;
    /*@NOTA: la opaciodad se indica con porcetanje. 1 es 100 de opacidad. Se Cambia la opacidad de la imagen
    del logo de GTS de la cabecera.
    ESTO ES AÑADIDO, no es original de la web.*/
    //Opacity: 0.2;
}


#header-right {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#header-right table {
    width: 1px;
}

#header-right table,
#header-right .search,
#header-right .wsite-search {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}

#header-right td {
    padding: 0;
}




/* TOP RIGHT: Phone Number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header-right .phone-number .wsite-text {
    color: #868686;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}

/* TOP RIGHT: Social Links
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header-right .wsite-social {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-item {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-rss {
    background: url(rss-h.png) no-repeat;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-linkedin {
    background: url(linkedin-h.png) no-repeat;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-facebook {
    background: url(facebook-h.png) no-repeat;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-twitter {
    background: url(twitter-h.png) no-repeat;
}

#header-right .wsite-social-mail {
    background: url(mail-h.png) no-repeat;
}

/* TOP RIGHT: Search Box
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header-right .search {
}

#header-right .wsite-search {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#header-right .wsite-search-input {
    width: 137px;
    height: 13px;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 8px 6px 8px !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #848484;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(input-bg.png) no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#header-right .wsite-search-button {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 27px;
    color: #010101;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(submit-bg-blue.png) no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#topnav {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#topnav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

#topnav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}

#topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #545454;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Actor", "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 15px 11px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
}

#topnav li#active a,
#topnav a:hover {
    color: #545454;
    background: #e3f3ff;
    border: 0;
}

/****************************** flyout menus ******************************/

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 9px;
    color: #545454;
    background: #e3f3ff;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b6d2e6;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
    color: #545454;
    background: #fdfeff;
}

/* main  */

#main {
}

#content {
    min-height: 400px;
    /*@NOTA: el padding modifica la separación entre las banderas con los idiomas el menú.*/
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#container {
    /*width: 920px;*/
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*
#banner-wrap {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 920px;
}
*/

/*
#banner-bot {
    background: url(banner-bot.png) left bottom no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}



#banner-top {
    background: url(banner-top.png) no-repeat;
    padding-top: 14px;
}



#banner-mid {
    background: url(banner-mid.png) repeat-y;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
*/

/*
#banner-outer {
    border: 6px solid #fff;
}
*/

/*
#banner {
    background: url(banner-top.png) no-repeat;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
*/

/* PAGE TYPE: banner-tall
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
.tall-header-page .wsite-header {
    width: 888px;
    height: 258px;
    background: url(banner-tall.jpg) no-repeat;
}
*/

/* PAGE TYPE: banner-short
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
.short-header-page .wsite-header {
    width: 888px;
    height: 168px;
    background: url(banner-short.jpg) no-repeat;
}
*/

.no-header-page #banner-wrap {
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

/*
.no-header-page #banner-bot {
    display: none;
}
*/

/* PAGE TYPE: banner-landing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.landing-page #banner {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.landing-page #banner-detail {
    background: #66c9c1;
}

#bannerleft {
    float: left;
    width: 504px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

/*
#banner-b {
    background: url(landing-bnr-mid-03.png) left bottom no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
*/

/*
#banner-t {
    background: url(landing-bnr-top.png) no-repeat;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
*/

/*
#banner-m {
    background: url(landing-bnr-mid.png) repeat-y;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
*/

#banner-inner {
    border: 6px solid #fff;
}

.landing-page .wsite-header {
    /*width: 472px;*/
    width: 1200px;
    height: 318px;
    background: url(banner-landing.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#bannerright {
    float: right;
    width: 366px;
    padding: 65px 25px 0 25px;
}

#bannerright h2 {
    color: #90cbf5;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0 0 12px 0;
}

#bannerright p {
    color: #868686;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin: 0;
}

#bannerright .wsite-button {
    margin: 0;
}

/* PAGE TYPE: splash
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.splash-page #header {
    width: 532px;
}

.splash-page #banner {
    width: 527px;
    height: 161px;
    padding: 6px 4px 4px 6px;
    background: url(banner-splash-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

.splash-page .wsite-header {
    width: 515px;
    height: 149px;
    background: url(banner-splash.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.splash-page #content-container {
    width: 528px;
}

.splash-page #content {
    width: 528px;
}

.splash-page #footer {
    width: 524px;
}

/* Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#footer-wrap {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    background: #fafafa;
    min-width: 920px;
}

#footer {
    padding: 40px 0 45px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
}

#footer p {
    color: #666;
}

#footer a {
    color: #919191;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #6ca9d5;
}

#footer h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 2px;
    padding: .3em 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #414141;
    font-family: "Actor", "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

#footer span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer .wsite-social {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer .wsite-social-item {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right:6px;
}

#footer .wsite-social-rss {
    background: url(rss.png) no-repeat;
}

#footer .wsite-social-linkedin {
    background: url(linkedin.png) no-repeat;
}

#footer .wsite-social-facebook {
    background: url(facebook.png) no-repeat;
}

#footer .wsite-social-twitter {
    background: url(twitter.png) no-repeat;
}

#footer .wsite-social-mail {
    background: url(mail-h.png) no-repeat;
}

.wsite-footer {  /* make sure enough space between element footer and attribution */
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Form Customization
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.wsite-form-label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #868686;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 12px 0 5px 0;
}

.form-radio-container {
    color: #868686;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.wsite-form-input {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #868686;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    padding: 8px 4px 5px !important;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 1;  /* background:#fff url(field.png) repeat-x;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        */
}

.form-select {
    color: #868686;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;  /*
            background:url#fff (field.png);
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        */
}

/* Footer Form Customization
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.wsite-form-container {
    margin-top:0px !important;
    text-align:left;
}

.wsite-footer .wsite-form-label {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px 0 2px 0;
}

.wsite-footer .wsite-form-field {
    width:300px !important;
}

.wsite-footer .form-radio-container {
    font-size:1em;
}

.wsite-footer .wsite-form-input {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.wsite-footer .form-select {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Buttons
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
  Buttons are styled with background image sprites. There are 4 unique image files:
   - small & normal-colored  (button_small_grey.png)
   - large & normal-colored  (button_large_grey.png)
   - small & highlight-colored  (button_small_orange.png)
   - large & highlight-colored  (button_large_orange.png)

  Each of these 4 types of buttons must define a :hover state (when user's mouse is over)
  as well as an :active state (when the user presses down).

  Look at the CSS (especially the inner .wsite-button-inner wrapper), as well as the
  image files to understand how the liquid-width nature of these buttons work.
 */

/* small */

.wsite-button {
    color: #333 !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    background: url(button.png) no-repeat 100% -105px;
}

.wsite-button:hover {
    background-position: 100% -140px;
}

.wsite-button:active {
    background-position: 100% -175px;
}

.wsite-button-inner {
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px 0 25px;
    background: url(button.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.wsite-button:hover .wsite-button-inner {
    background-position: 0 -35px;
}

.wsite-button:active .wsite-button-inner {
    background-position: 0 -70px;
}

/* large */

.wsite-button-large {
    height: 41px;
    background: url(button_large.png) no-repeat 100% -126px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.wsite-button-large:hover {
    background-position: 100% -168px;
}

.wsite-button-large:active {
    background-position: 100% -210px;
}

.wsite-button-large .wsite-button-inner {
    height: 41px;
    line-height: 41px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 25px;
    background: url(button_large.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.wsite-button-large:hover .wsite-button-inner {
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}

.wsite-button-large:active .wsite-button-inner {
    background-position: 0 -84px;
}

/* highlight */

/*
Making the highlighted versions of the buttons is easy because we just need
to switch out the background images. This works because the different button
states (normal, :hover, :active) have their sprite coordinates in the same places.
*/

.wsite-button-large.wsite-button-highlight {
    background-image: url(button_large_highlight_blue.png);
}

.wsite-button-large.wsite-button-highlight .wsite-button-inner {
    background-image: url(button_large_highlight_blue.png);
}

.wsite-button-highlight {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-image: url(button_highlight_blue.png);
}

.wsite-button-highlight .wsite-button-inner {
    background-image: url(button_highlight_blue.png);
}
```

And my html code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body class=' tall-header-page  wsite-theme-dark'>
<div id="header-wrap">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header-container">
            <table id="header">
                <tr>
                    <td id="logo">{logo}</td>
                    <td id="header-right">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="phone-number">{phone:text}</td>
                                <td class="social">{social}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="search">{search}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="topnav">
                {menu}
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="banner-wrap">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner-bot">
            <div id="banner">
                <div id="banner-mid">
                    <div id="banner-outer">
                        <div class="wsite-header"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main-wrap">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">{content}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrap">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="footer">{footer}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how to change the width of the logo, the header, to fit to the width of the page.

And if it is possible, how to fit the width of the page to the width of the browser, so when a user change the size of the window browser, fit the content to the browser size.

Thanks.

Comment: Either use percentage-based width/height values or use JavaScript to update the layout when the window resizes. I highly recommend looking into making your layout responsive by the use of percentage-based widths/heights. Also, thanks for the code but that's too much. You should post the code that has to do with the issue at hand, CSS for the footer is not necessary...

Comment: Also... __don't use tables to layout websites__ !!

Comment: Take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). They'll help you.

Comment: @Paulie_D But why? Even Facebook uses them.

Comment: @EisaAdil Semantically, tables are for showing tabular data. Meaning browsers take that into consideration and do funny things that have to be "reset" with CSS to make not occur. I'm currently dealing with a Chrome specific error where a column of cells resizes seemingly by itself, most likely due to the complex layout around the table structure. Also, Facebook doing something is **in no way, shape or form** a good reason for anyone else to do that thing. They live in a different world than 99% of web developers.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for the valuable advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resolution/size of the browser depends on the client, you can solve this in the client side.

I suggest looking into JavaScript as it has these handy functions (and more):

```
// Get the page width
windowWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;

// Get the page height
windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
```